# After the last execution, it can no longer be executed

Tags: npm, visual-studio-code, nodemon, errno, enoent

The last time I worked, it worked fine, but when I ran it today it didn't work.
Even if I searched on Google, the -4058 code did not come out, so I am asking a question.
I'm making it while watching YouTube. I hope there is a good solution.
I don't think it's an installation issue since I haven't touched anything after the last operation.
[image]

Comment: Try search 4058 instead of -4058 because Google assume `-` as "exclude this word". The code means "no such file or directory", looks like npm can't find package.js file for some reason.

Comment: Thank you for leaving the answer.
The problem was that I did'npm start' in the top folder. I do it in the folder where the json file is located and it works fine!
If you have a problem like me, please check the route well and try.